# How to remember if a user has closed a dropdown div

Tags: jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu

I have a little drop down message I want to add to a site, it uses the following code

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$('#someid1') .slideDown('slow');}); $(document).ready(function() $('#hide').click(function(){
 $('#someid1').slideUp('slow'); });});</script>


<div id="someid1"><div id="someid2">some gibberish <a id="hide" href="#">HERE</a></div></div>
```

when the user clicks here to hide I want to remember this choice. Problem is I know I probably need a cookie to do this but don't have a clue about them any help appreciated

thanks in advance Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use a cookie; you can try storing the data using [store.js](https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/store-js), which encapsulates browser local storage and a few other methods to store data on the client side.

```
/*
store.js groups your values into something called a store. Multiple stores are separated from each other.
So let's make a new store:
*/

var settings = new Store("settings");

/*
Just choose a name for the new store, and save it in a variable. Always remember to use the "new" keyword! Never leave it off!
Now you can almost normally get, set and remove values:
*/

settings.set("color", "blue");
settings.set("enable_test1", true);
settings.set("number_of_rainbows", 8);

// and

var color = settings.get("color");

// and

settings.remove("color");
```

...edit with code..

```
 <div id="cookiemsg"><div id="cookiecenter"><p>This website places a
 Google Analytics cookie on your machine, this helps us collect
 anonymous information so that we can provide a better experiance for
 you. By using this site you imply your consent to this. For more
 information or to find out how you can remove this cookie please visit
 our privacy policy <a href="#">HERE</a> or if you are happy with this
 click <a id="hide" href="#">HERE</a></p></div><!--end of
 cookiecenter--></div><!--end of cookiemsg-->
```

​

> 

```
$(function(){
    var store = new Store("com.domain.page.store")
    var acceptedCookie = store.get("acceptedCookie");
    if(typeof acceptedCookie == "undefined"){
     //set a default
       acceptedCookie = false
     }
    if(!acceptedCookie){
        $('#cookiemsg').slideDown('slow');
    }

    $('#hide').click(function(){
         $('#cookiemsg').slideUp('slow');
         store.set("acceptedCookie", true);
   });

});
```

Comment: okay so how would I implement this solution, there has to be an easy way that once a user has clicked the here link with the id hide it remembers it

Comment: I'm afraid my javascript is poor, but I have found my self in a situation where I need to use it

Comment: Thank you, can't get it to work at the moment, but theres enough to be fiddling with. Do i need to still set the div to display:none with css. thankyou I'm sure ill get there in the end

Comment: Well it should work, basically if you make a change, then hit run the change is saved for the page reload. Id put a display none in there if default state for your item was hidden.

Comment: basically div1 was a container and div two had the content centred. I wanted both divs to slide down on page load then when the here button was clicked i wanted the divs to slide back up and for it to remember this choice

Comment: Here is a link to the code I started with, it does what I want just when the user clicks here i want it to remember that other wise the message drops down on each page load, hope this makes more sense [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/uNDn8/

Comment: Thank you, will it only work on a live site?, testing locally at the moment

Answer (score 3):

Try this jQuery Plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie It's a simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for reading, writing and deleting cookies.

You can simply **create** Cookies

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

And **read** Cookies

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
```

So you **ask for** it...

```
if ($.cookie('the_cookie') === 'the_value') {
    $('#someid1').addClass('open');
}
```

**CSS**

```
#someid1 {
    display:none;
}

#someid1.open {
    display:block
}
```

**Example Implemtation**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

        <!-- Get jQuery Core -->
        <script src="/path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Get Cookie Plugin -->
        <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Is DOM ready?
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#hide').click(function(e){

                    // Set Cookie named 'notification'to the value 'hide'
                    $.cookie('notification', 'hide'); 

                    // Hide your Div
                    $('#someid1').slideUp('slow');

                    // Disable default behavior
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                // Hide DIV is Cookie is Set
                if( $.cookie('notification') === 'hide' ){
                    $('#someid1').hide();
                }

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someid1">

            <div id="someid2">some gibberish</div>
            <a id="hide" href="#">HERE</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** This code is not tested and might not be work. But it gives you a hint to the right direction.

Comment: I added the following code to my document it doesn't work. I don't understand the bit that says the_cookie and the_value, am I meant to change this and if so to what?<script>

$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 365 });

if ($.cookie('the_cookie') === 'the_value') {
    $('#cookiemsg').addClass('hide');
}

</script>

Comment: Is the plugin initiated? You have to put this `<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` under your jQuery call...

Comment: the_cookie is the Name of the Cookie. Could be 'message' or 'notification'. the_value represents the Value. Like message_hidden or true/false

Comment: A cookie stores his data as key=>value pair. Maybe this helps: http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#1.1

Comment: I have used you code but the div won't slide up on click I have changed the id's to match mine

Comment: Please Update your Question and provide some Code.

Comment: here is a link to what I started with, its works and does exactly what i want, all i need to do is get it to remember when a user clicks the here link [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/uNDn8

Comment: Thank you gears digital for all your help, I have used the solution below in the end but you were great for coming up with the first solution